# ajax request header strange behaviour

Tags: ajax, header, get, jersey

I'm experiencing something somewhat strange with regards to setting the accept header between different browsers.

When using Firefox, the default header seems to be text/html. However the default header on chrome seems to be application/json.

I have cleared my browser cache for both and still I see the same behaviour.

My objective is to set the header type for a simple REST API GET so that the jersey resource can content negotiate the appropriate response type but due to the above I'm getting inconsistent behaviour.

I believe I'm doing something very silly but if someone can point out why I would experience the above that would be great help.

thanks

the ajax header I am setting is as follows and I change the header type accordingly.

```
myGetRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: ok so apologies for being a knob.

The request header should be 'Accept' not 'Content-Type':

    myGetRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); // wrong
    myGetRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); // yup

thanks hope this helps someone who may come across such a problem.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request header should be 'Accept' not 'Content-Type':

```
myGetRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```